# How to extract key and value from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files, extract, key-value

I would like to extract key and value from an existing text file. Key in a separate variable and value in a separate variable.

The text file (sample.txt) contains the below content,

```
one:two
three:four
five:six
seven:eight
nine:ten
sample:demo
```

I am able to read the content from the text file, but i am not able to proceed further to extract key and value.

```
with open ("sampletxt.txt", "r") as hfile:
    sp = hfile.read()
    print (sp)

x=0
for line in sp:
    sp.split(":")[x].strip()
    x+=1
```

The above only extracts the value and also provides index out of range exception at the end.

```
If we iterate through the file, i am expecting the output as below,

Key 0 = one
Key 1 = three
Key 2 = five
Key 3 = seven
key 4 = sample

Value 0 = two
Value 1 = four
Value 2 = six
Value 3 = eight
Value 4 = ten
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
with open ("sampletxt.txt", "r") as hfile:
  sp = hfile.read()
  print (sp)

lines = sp.split("\n")
for line in lines:
  # print("line:[{0}]".format(line))
  parts = line.split(":")
  print("key:[{0}], value:[{1}]".format(parts[0], parts[1]))
```

Comment: Windsting, it works. However i am getting the below exception along the results,   
 line 21, in <module>
    print("key:[{0}], value:[{1}]".format(parts[0], parts[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: That error means the length of `parts` is less than `2`, hence the `line` is very likely not contains a character `:`, uncomment that print to check it.

Comment: Sure will check.. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

It can work:

```py
sp = open ("sampletxt.txt", "r")
x=0
key=[]
value=[]
try:
    while True:
        text_line = sp.readline()
        if text_line:
            text_line = ''.join(text_line)
            text_line = text_line.split()
            text_line = ''.join(text_line).split(':')
            key.append(text_line[0])
            value.append(text_line[1])
            x += 1
        else:
            for i in range(x):
                print("Key {} = {}".format(i,key[i]))
            print("")
            for i in range(x):
                print("Value {} = {}".format(i,value[i]))
            break
finally:
    sp.close()
```

The output is:

```
Key 0 = one
Key 1 = three
Key 2 = five
Key 3 = seven
Key 4 = nine
Key 5 = sample

Value 0 = two
Value 1 = four
Value 2 = six
Value 3 = eight
Value 4 = ten
Value 5 = demo
```

which is similar to your request

Comment: Hi, I am facing an issue when the value has got white space between two strings, the white is ignored in the logic of code that you have given. Can you please advise ? Example, if the value is hello world, then it is taken as helloworld. But i need the actual value including white space.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:

```py
with open ("sampletxt.txt", "r") as hfile:
    sp = hfile.read()
    print (sp)

dictionary = {}
for x, line in enumerate(sp):
    line_list = sp.split(":")
    dictionary[line_list[0]]=line_list[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always check if `split` returns two members (or any number you expect) **before** using the indexes.